# Elasticsearch performance with vectors - array vs keys

Tags: performance, elasticsearch

I am setting up an elasticsearch instance whereby I am vectorising videos by frame.

My approach currently is to take each video (no matter the length) and vectorise it in 5-10 equally space frames, and then store these as keys in the object.

However, a more accurate approach would be to take "a frame every 3 seconds" for instance and then whatever length that is, query against that.

However, I'm wary of the performance differences?

If my object is:

```
{
"frame_1": [x....y],
"frame_2": [x1...y1]
...
}
```

vs

```
{
"frames": [
[x....y],
[x1...y1]
]
}
```

would the 2nd be markably slower?

Answer (score 1):

In option 1 you have a dynamic number of keys, and your search queries will likely require to search within all the keys. While in option 2 you only have one key to store and to search. So I would assume that option 2 would even be slightly faster to search as your data model is smaller, because it requires less keys.

However, as for all performance related questions: It would be the best to create a proof of concept example for both approaches and measure the difference on a production like dataset.